# Print the common of the two files

Tags: grep

I want to print the common of the 2 file

One file contain the `ls -l` option and the other one have the `ls` option

`ls` only has the file name 
`ls -l` has everything including the permission and other info.

Is there a way for them to print the output of the common one? The comm command doesn't seem to work (it prints everything)

I tried `grep -f file1 file2` but nothing shows up

lets say the `ls -l` output is

```
-rwx------ 1 username 230 date and the filename
```

`ls` is

```
filname
```

I am trying to get the filename aka the union of the 2 file. I don't think there is a way for it to read the filename directory in shell

I want the

```
filename
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're trying to do? Are you trying to find the union of filenames listed in both files?

Comment: @daxelrod modded the first post read above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in ls-file; do grep -e $i$ ls-l-file; done
```

This loops through each line in `ls-file` (containing only the ls command) and assigns the output to $i.  It then greps the `ls-l-file` (containing the ls -l command) and looks for a match, and outputs it.

**Update**

```
for i in ls-file; do grep -eo $i$ ls-l-file; done
```

The -o parameter will only output the matching text, so just the filename

**Update 2**

```
while read i; do  grep -oe $i$ ls-l-file; done < ls-file
```

This works better.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work correctly if a filename is the same as the name of an owner or group of a file in ls-l-file, for example.

Comment: Good point. I have edited to match only the end of a line

Comment: oh this works like a charm ,I been trying comm and diff ,and all sorts of grep command all day

Answer (score 0):

You're part of the way there.

The first thing you need is to extract just the filenames from the file containing `ls -l` output, you can do so with

```
awk '{print $9}' < lsl_file
```

On my OS, the filename is the 9th column, it's possible it may be a different column on yours.

Note that `comm` requires both files to be sorted, this should already be the case with the output of `ls` and `ls -l`.

Therefore, your one-liner would be:

```
awk '{print $9}' < lsl_file | comm - ls_file
```

The single dash argument to comm tells it to use STDIN.

**Important Assumption**: this assumes that your filenames do not have spaces in them.